# Troubles with ocaml regexp, basic patterns don't work

Tags: regex, ocaml

I have this regex which works:

```
Str.string_match (Str.regexp "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\\.[0-9][0-9]\\.[0-9][0-9]") dir 0
```

But I want to simplify it and it simply doesn't work

```
"\\d{4}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}"
```

There were other attempts to make it work but i came to the conclusion that it has troubles with the d, {} and even with grouping chars with ()
This patterns work in any other language and are used even in this huge list of examples http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_ocaml/patternmatching.html

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Please let me know if it's doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation of the `Str` module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Str.html) you'll find that Perl-style notations like `\d` are not supported.

There is a [Perl-Compatible Regular Expression library](http://mmottl.github.io/pcre-ocaml/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different library that supports the "\d" syntax, like [ocaml-re](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-re) (which is written in pure OCaml and supports multiple regex syntaxes, including POSIX and a subset of PCRE).

For example:

```
$ opam install re

$ ocaml
# #use "topfind";;
# #require "re.pcre";;
# let re = Re_pcre.regexp "\\d{4}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}";;
# Re.execp re "1234.01.243";;
- : bool = true
# Re.execp re "1234.501.24";;
- : bool = false
```